# How to authenticate Node.js api and web socket connections with identity server 4

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, socket.io, identityserver4

`HI,

I have an use case to send the push notifications to web app through node js api application. How to authenticate Node.js api and web socket connections with identity server 4.(OpenID)

```
io.use(function (socket, next) {
try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
    var currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    if (decodedToken.aud.includes(apiapplicationId) && decodedToken.iss === identityServerUrl ) {
        console.log("data");
        next();
    }
    else {
        next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    }
}
catch (err) {
                next(new Error('Authentication error'));
            }
});
```

I am trying this way but its looping continuous socket calls in network`